# sql - select slow of two table

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have two table in my mariadb database, A and B :

my request is very slow 3 min 18.028 sec min with index.

sql request :

```
select A.Cid, A.time, A.step, B.cpu 
from A
join B on B.CID2 = A.CID group by A.CID;
```

first table A :

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |
344039 rows in set (1.239 sec)
```

second table B ( :

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
51639 rows in set (0.181 sec)
```

request result:

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |          0.03   |
```

405 rows in set (3 min 18.028 sec)

mariadb config:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                                          | Value                |
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| aria_block_size                                        | 8192                 |
| aria_log_file_size                                     | 1073741824           |
| aria_max_sort_file_size                                | 9223372036853727232  |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size                             | 134217728            |
| aria_pagecache_file_hash_size                          | 512                  |
| aria_sort_buffer_size                                  | 268434432            |
| binlog_cache_size                                      | 32768                |
| binlog_file_cache_size                                 | 16384                |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                                 | 32768                |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                                | 8388608              |
| delayed_queue_size                                     | 1000                 |
| histogram_size                                         | 0                    |
| host_cache_size                                        | 279                  |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                          | 134217728            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                                | 536870912            |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size                          | 25                   |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                                   | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                               | 84                   |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                               | 3                    |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                             | 640000000            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                                 | 16777216             |
| innodb_log_file_size                                   | 50331648             |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size                            | 8192                 |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                               | 10485760             |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size                       | 134217728            |
| innodb_page_size                                       | 16384                |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                                | 300                  |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                                | 1048576              |
| innodb_sync_array_size                                 | 1                    |
| join_buffer_size                                       | 134217728            |
| key_buffer_size                                        | 134217728            |
| key_cache_block_size                                   | 1024                 |
| key_cache_file_hash_size                               | 512                  |
| large_page_size                                        | 0                    |
| log_tc_size                                            | 24576                |
| max_binlog_cache_size                                  | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                                        | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                             | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_heap_table_size                                    | 16777216             |
| max_join_size                                          | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_long_data_size                                     | 16777216             |
| max_relay_log_size                                     | 1073741824           |
| metadata_locks_cache_size                              | 1024                 |
| mrr_buffer_size                                        | 262144               |
| myisam_block_size                                      | 1024                 |
| myisam_data_pointer_size                               | 6                    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size                              | 9223372036853727232  |
| myisam_mmap_size                                       | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                                | 134216704            |
| performance_schema_accounts_size                       | -1                   |
| performance_schema_digests_size                        | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size     | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_size          | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_size      | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size      | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size           | -1                   |
| performance_schema_hosts_size                          | -1                   |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size          | -1                   |
| performance_schema_setup_actors_size                   | 100                  |
| performance_schema_setup_objects_size                  | 100                  |
| performance_schema_users_size                          | -1                   |
| preload_buffer_size                                    | 32768                |
| profiling_history_size                                 | 15                   |
| query_alloc_block_size                                 | 16384                |
| query_cache_size                                       | 0                    |
| query_prealloc_size                                    | 24576                |
| range_alloc_block_size                                 | 4096                 |
| read_buffer_size                                       | 131072               |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                                   | 262144               |
| rowid_merge_buff_size                                  | 8388608              |
| sort_buffer_size                                       | 2097152              |
| thread_cache_size                                      | 4                    |
| thread_pool_size                                       | 2                    |
| tmp_disk_table_size                                    | 18446744073709551615 |
| tmp_memory_table_size                                  | 16777216             |
| tmp_table_size                                         | 16777216             |
| transaction_alloc_block_size                           | 8192                 |
| transaction_prealloc_size                              | 4096                 |
| wsrep_max_ws_size                                      | 2147483647           |
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

my config:

[root/]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3788        1177         143          10        2467        2326
Swap:          1535         284        1251

processor : Intel Celeron_4x0 (Conroe/Merom Class Core 2)

my question is how to increase the speed of my request ?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: Would this question been better if placed on dba.stackexchange?

Comment: We will need the relevant schema too.

Comment: Start by using JOIN its a bit more 20th century

Comment: @Vatev how can i have the schema ?

Comment: When a `SELECT` uses more than a single table, please prepend each column with the table alias.

Comment: @RiggSFolly i used join but i have many row, i have 344039 for table A and 51639 for table B

Comment: @dfgert "the schema" means the tables (column types and indexes). Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table`.

Comment: `from A,B` is not using `JOIN`

Comment: Why are you `group by CID` as it looks like a One to One relationship to me

Comment: What are the **primary keys**, **foreign keys**, **unique constraints**, and **existing indexes** on these tables?

Comment: What is the current state of your computer ? If the CPU is 100% occupied doing other things or your memory is constantly swapping you can get bad performance.

Comment: my memory is 100% and cpu is 100%

Answer (score 1):

You have "bare" columns in the `group by` -- and this would generate errors in almost any database.

The following may be faster:

```
select A.Cid, A.time, A.step,
       (select B.cpu 
        from B 
        where B.CID2 = A.CID
        limit 1
       ) as cpu
from A;
```

For performance you want an index on `B(CID2, cpu)`.

Note that this actually does a `LEFT JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`.  If that is an important distinction (i.e., you really want only rows that match between the two tables), then add:

```
having cpu is not null
```

Comment: If `A.Cid` were the primary key of the table, yes. Or at least if it had a unique constraint. Otherwise this is not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You coul try optimizing the JOIN

```
        select distinct Cid
                , time
                , step
                , cpu 
        from A
        INNER JOIN B ON B.CID2=A.CID
```

adding proper index for yhis so   be sure you index on  table b

```
create index  idx1  on B(CID2)
```

and on table a adding  a composite redundant index

```
    create index  idx2  on A(CID,time, step, cpu )
```

You should avoid group by without aggregation funtion for get distinct result use distinct for this  ( the use of group by without aggregation function produce error in most recente mysql version and produce unpredictable result for the older)
and you should avoid old implicit join sintax but use explicit the result is the same but the explicit syntax is more clear

Comment: query is very slow, do you have an idea ?, may be its the config of mariadb, i tested with mysql (same issue) slow query

Comment: have you created the indexes  as suggested ??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use 'group by' ?

Try this:

```
select Cid, A.time, step, cpu from A,B where B.CID2=A.CID
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff that not work :

select A.Cid, A.time, A.step,
       (select B.cpu 
        from B 
        where B.CID2 = A.CID
        limit 1
       ) as cpu
from A;